# What kind of remote server service was I using?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, remote-server

I’m part of a very small company that uses a database hosted on a server (104.131.##.###). However, the server no longer responds and the person who set up and owns the server space has already left the company. This past employee seems disgruntled so they won’t help. It’s complicated, but we decided to open a new server. The only issue is, I don’t know what we were using.

**What I do know** is I would access and change the database at http://104.131.##.###/phpmyadmin/ (image of login below)

I also had php files stored on the server using Filezilla (in a “var” folder, if that helps) which were accessed via path: http://104.131.96.###/path/to/file.php

I’ve set up a version of the same server using xampp on my own computer, but I can’t keep my computer running constantly.

So my question is, what service were we using / should we use? Where would I start to set up a new server like this? (I still have the php files and can recreate the db)

I've looked into AWS and digitalOcean, but I'm in a bit over my head and  can't tell if they're offering what we need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you have some experience with docker and dev-ops, i would recommend setting up the server/s in docker. Else you will want to install php, mysql and a web server (apache, traefik, nginx, lighttpd, etc). The thing you got an image from is a package called phpmyadmin, it can be installed from the apt-repository or by installing it manually.

Comment: If you have no experience in this at all, I would recommend contacting someone who does and hire them to set up your server. Security is important and working with servers on a production environment requires knowledge to make sure its secure!

Comment: I could not agree more with @Jite ... especially since this is for a business and not a hobby project.  There are just too many little things to know about to set up a working secure environment that won't leave you with long term regrets.  This really is time for a pro.  What city are you in?

Comment: @Jite It's a small not-for-profit I do work for on the side. They don't have the resources to hire a pro. I have some minor experience working with xammp, but not docker. I just need to know which online service to fits the bill. The server stores basic data, some email addresses and app data and that's all. No passwords even, so security isn't much of a worry.

Comment: If it's just for database and nothing else, I would recommend checking a hosted database service. If you need php and such too, a VM via DO or AWS is probably a good idea. When it comes to the resources, it might be worth trying to find some type of pro-bono sys/dev -op which could do it for the exposure only.

Comment: I just realised @Jite was the guy who recommended Docker.  Although I do love Docker, I would recommend you stay far away from it.  It only adds more skill requirement and complexity to your particular situation.  Your tech stack should not far exceed your available skills.  I think what you need is a managed MySQL environ so someone else is worrying about the database.  My long time preference is WebFaction but I think DigitalOcean also does the same.

Comment: As @BareNakedCoder says, if you have no experience in it, stay away from it in a production environment! :)

Comment: This question is not really a good fit for Stack Overflow, which says in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that they want to see questions about specific programming problems, not open-ended questions asking for recommendations of tools or platforms. Also the answers to this question are likely to be opinion-based, which is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The server was using phpmyadmin and mysql and Digital Ocean.

So you need at least a LAMP stack. With the info given we can't help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the help! On Digital Ocean, there's an option for "One-click apps". These options include LAMP and phpMyAdmin. Which on should I choose? Do I need LAMP?